# Request["key"] vs Request.Params["key"] vs Request.QueryString["key"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

`Request["key"]` vs `Request.Params["key"]` vs `Request.QueryString["key"]`

Which method do you seasoned programmers use? and why?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I recommend `Request.QueryString["key"]`. There isn't a lot of difference to `Request["Key"]` for a query string but there is a big(er) difference if you are trying to get the value from `ServerVariables`. `Request["Key"]` looks for a value in `QueryString` if null, it looks at `Form`, then `Cookie` and finally `ServerVariables`.

Using `Params` is the most costly. The first request to params creates a new `NameValueCollection` and adds each of the `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookie` and `ServerVariables` to this collection. For the second request on it is more performant than `Request["Key"]`.

Having said that the performance difference for a couple of keys is fairly negligable. The key here is code should show intent and using `Request.QueryString` makes it clear what your intent is.

Comment: Thanks, you just answered my question as to why cookie values are popping out of my Request.Params[index].

Comment: Great that you noted that a new NameValueCollection is created on first call, now my error and stack trace makes sense :)

Answer (score 24):

I prefer to use `Request.QueryString["key"]` because it helps the code-reader know **exactly** where you are getting the data from. I tend not to use `Request.Params["key"]` because it could refer to a cookie, query string and a few other things; so the user has to think a little. The less time someone needs to figure out what you are thinking, the easier it is to maintain the code.

Comment: I think the issue is really `where` the the data are coming from. It's fine to use `Request.Params["key"]` as long as you actually don't care whether it's coming from the query string or from somewhere else.

Comment: If you know which collection the value is contained in, look there. No use making the Request object search all the collections(for performance reasons if nothing else).

Comment: @Will Vousden. Nice point. Your point is very true when you first write the code and the idea is fresh in your head. Fast-Forward two years from now- you have a nasty bug, the code is very hairy/complex and you just want to focus on fixing the problem! Not having to do hunt for the meaning  of a variable populated with "Request.Params["key"]" (query string, session variable or something else)can make things a tad easier. It is not huge or make-or-break and you can always look it up; but little things like that go a long way.

Answer (score 7):

`HttpRequest.Params` or `Request.Params` gets just about everything (querystring, form, cookie and session variables) from the httprequest, whereas `Request.Querystring` only will pull the querystring... all depends on what you are doing at the time.

Answer (score 5):

I always explicitly specify the collection.  If for some reason you want to allow overrides, code the "get" for each one and write some clear code that shows your hierarchy for choosing one over the other.  IMO, I dislike getting a value from multiple sources without a clear business reason for so doing.

Answer (score 1):

As a kindly notice, If you set **requestValidationMode="4.5"** under web.config, both *Request.QueryString[“key”]* and *Request[“key”]* will use "lazy loading" behavior as design.

However, somehow *Request.Params[“key”]* will still trigger validation as the behavior of 4.0 .

This odd behavior really confuses me for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Always found it more useful to target url params with the request.querystring, it saves the headache of trying to track down other values it can grab from various other locations.