# How to Post values from iPhone using ASIHttp?

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net, objective-c, asihttprequest

I want to send some values from my iPhone application to an ASp.Net web page in server. I am using  asihttp for that. Its processing the request and invoking the page on server. But the none of the values are retrieved in server side. Below is the code from iPhone app.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"abc" forKey:@"from"];
    [request setPostValue:@"abc" forKey:@"name"];
    [request setPostValue:@"abc" forKey:@"phone"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
```

On Server side I am using asp.net c#. THis is the code using for retriving values. But I am getting emtpy string?

```
sendMail(Request.QueryString["name"],Request.QueryString["from"],Request.QueryString["phone"]);
```

Could Someone help Please?

Comment: Try to NSLog out the response from the request. Use [request responseData];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Request.QueryString["name"]` will retrieve a post parameter. You either need to change your ASIHttpRequest to include the parameters in the query string, or modify your ASP.NET code to expect post parameters.

You could try `Request.Form["name"]`, `Request.Form["phone"]`, etc. on the server side.

Or, you could try:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?name=%@&...",urlString,name,...];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

on the client side.

Comment: Request.QueryString is for retrieving GET parameters. If you're using MVC in .NET, you could simply annotate your method as [HttpPost] and define the parameters in your method signature.

Answer (score 0):

QueryString is for values in the URL. A post will have values in Request.Form or just Request which will search through QueryString & Form for the values.

Another question with more detail about QueryString vs Form.

[Request["key"] vs Request.Params["key"] vs Request.QueryString["key"]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312855/requestkey-vs-request-paramskey-vs-request-querystringkey-c-asp-net)