# Is there any difference between Request("key") and Request.Params("key")?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, httprequest

In an ASP.NET MVC3 application I have a function that looks like:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething(controllerCtx As ControllerContext)
    ....

    ' Which to use? and Why?
    Dim val = controllerCtx.HttpContext.Request.Params.Item("someKey")
    Dim val = controllerCtx.HttpContext.Request.Item("someKey")

    ....
End Sub
```

(*I'm aware that `Item` is a `Default` property in both and can be removed, that's not relevant in this question.*)

Looking at the MSDN pages for [`Request.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.item.aspx) and [`Params.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.params.aspx), I'm not seeing any differences.  Both pages say they get values from: Cookies, Form, QueryString, or ServerVariables collections. (though they do list the orders differently.)

I've seen [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312855/requestkey-vs-request-paramskey-vs-request-querystringkey-c-asp-net), but it seems the answers focused on the `QueryString` component moreso than the `Request.Params.Item` vs `Request.Item`.

Why would would I use one over the other? Is there any difference between the two at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are strictly equivalent in terms of contents. And here's the contents and the order in which it is searched:

1. QueryString
2. Form
3. Cookies
4. ServerVariables

As far as which one to use, well, in an ASP.NET MVC application it would be better to use:

```
controllerCtx.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("someKey");
```

as this take into account routes and custom value providers (such as for example the JsonValueProvider) as well. But of course everything would depend on your scenario and specific requirements.