# how to get the value from address bar entered by client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I don't know how to put the title but i will try to explain it the requirement here.
Normally user entered an URL in address bar in browser, for example **www.example.com**, then click a link and redirect to another page **www.example.com/test.aspx**. Alternatively, user also can just enter/type **www.example.com/test.aspx** from address bar if they know the full path.

So, i required to write a code where user can type an URL in address bar, for example **www.example.com/test.aspx?usr="www.test.com"**. (note: with addition **usr="www.test.com"**)

The **"usr="www.test.com"** after **www.example.com/test.aspx?** contain a value that stored in database.
So, when the user type **www.example.com/test.aspx?usr="www.test.com"** it will search the database for matching **www.test.com** and do some process if found.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking here. Reading a querystring, connectong to a database, and executing some code are all far too broad topics to cover. To you have a specific programming question you wish to ask?

Comment: Million thanks for those who answer, all the answer is correct for my case. That what i am searching. Tried google but that guy understand just a simple/short question not a long explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) to get value any param passed to the page.
The result, stored in a page variable, can be used to retrieve the needed data.

```
string usr = Request.QueryString["usr"];
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value is being passed through in the query string (the part after the '?'), you can just check for it using the Request object.

C#

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request["usr"];
// Then perform your search based on the value in URL.
```

Note: You can also use `string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["usr"];` if you want to ensure that your value of `usr` is only from the query string and not a POST or COOKIE. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312855/requestkey-vs-request-paramskey-vs-request-querystringkey-c-sharp-as) for further info.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values in url after `?` from HttpContext using

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request["usr"];
```