# Client side redirect (from address bar)

Tags: javascript, redirect, client-side, address-bar

In a client side script (JavaScript, HTML etc.) how do I make the page redirect to a link specified in the address bar when a function had been called.

Example: Address bar says: Example.com/(code containing redirect link)

When a certain function is called, for example, it will redirect to a page specified in the "(code containing redirect link)"

Here is a question similar (it isn't client side, like what I need): [how to get the value from address bar entered by client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027584/how-to-get-the-value-from-address-bar-entered-by-client)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the get parameter of the url in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/use-the-get-parameter-of-the-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do that but here goes:

```
//Sets location for current window       
window.location = window.location.pathname; // Get the string after the /
```